# Replace all integers in a dictionary's values with zeros or string

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, replace

This is what I have:

`d1 = {"00f_5" :["AAA","AAC",3], 'oof_6': ["CCC",2,3]}`

I would like:

`d2 = {"00f_5" :["AAA","AAC",0], 'oof_6': ["CCC",0,0]}`

`d2 = {"00f_5" :["AAA","AAC",Ref], 'oof_6': ["CCC",Ref,Ref]}`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do that like this, with a dictionary comprehension:

```
d1 = {"00f_5" :["AAA","AAC",3], 'oof_6': ["CCC",2,3]}

out = {key: [value if not isinstance(value, int) else 0 for value in lst] 
           for key, lst in d1.items()}

print(out)
# {'00f_5': ['AAA', 'AAC', 0], 'oof_6': ['CCC', 0, 0]}
```

For each sublist, we use a list comprehension, keeping the value if it isn't an `int`, replacing it (here by 0, but you can put a string here instead) otherwise.

Comment: E 501: line too long (101 > 79 characters)

Comment: @MykolaZotko I cut it in two so that you don't get any warning anymore :)

Comment: Good code should be readable. But at SO everything is packed in one line.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a dictionary and list comprehension

```
{i:[x if type(x)!=int else 0 for x in d1[i]] for i in d1}
```

output:

```
{'00f_5': ['AAA', 'AAC', 0], 'oof_6': ['CCC', 0, 0]}
```

Briefly, the dictionary comprehension goes over all keys and inserts as a value a list comprehension. The list comprehension goes over all values in the original item (d1[i]) and replaces all integers with 0. You can modify this to whatever you want.

Comment: I did not send the answer because you are outrunning me :). I wrote a similar code, but in another syntax :). I give my thumbs up. `{key : [0 if type(x) is int else x for x in values] for key,values in d1.items()}`

Answer (score 0):

this should do the trick:

```
d1 = {"00f_5" :["AAA","AAC",3], 'oof_6': ["CCC",2,3]}

for key in d1:
    for i in range(len(d1[key])):
        if isinstance(d1[key][i], int):
            d1[key][i] = 0
```